# How to share wifi under Gentoo?

Tags: kde, gentoo, wifi-hotspot

My system is Gentoo 64bit, with KDE. I want to share my wifi connection with other devices. I am able to do this with Windows 7, so I think my device is able to setup an AP. And I find out that in KDE, the NetworkManager can set up a *shared* wifi connection.

But my problem is, after I setup this *shared* wifi connection profile, I cannot activate it. I can not see it from the network connection drop down list, neither can I find it with my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the configuration file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directly. System wide connections don't have `permissions=` line in the `[connection]` section. Also, NetworkManager is monitoring available connections via wpa_supplicant which triggers network scanning. You normally only connect to networks that are public, i.e. not hidden. If your network uses hidden SSID, the best way is to turn of this feature, as it doesn't provide security anyway. If you cannot do that, you'd have to ask KDE developers or use `nmcli` or `nm-applet` to connect to the network.

See also:

- https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/0.9/ref-settings.html